# Temporary table related issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I am stuck at a point where I need to find unique records from a table. My query is working  fine when I test it the database but I want to run this query on a set of multiple temporary tables. However with, temporary tables, I am getting issues. I am hoping if I can find solution here.

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE member_temp_one (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'address',
`Address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Phone` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`City` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'city',
`State` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ST',
`ZIP` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000',
`reference_number` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`end_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`start_date` varchar(50)
);
```

Followed by the other tables I am using

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE member_temp_2 SELECT * FROM member_temp_one WHERE 1;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE member_temp_unique as SELECT t.* FROM `member_temp_one` t 
where 
(CASE t.reference_number
WHEN 0 THEN 
t.id = (select max(t2.id) from `member_temp_2` t2 where t2.Firstname = t.Firstname AND t2.Lastname = t.Lastname AND t.EMAIL = t2.EMAIL)
ELSE
t.start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) from `member_temp_2` t3 WHERE t3.reference_number = t.reference_number order by t3.start_date desc, t3.id desc limit 1)
END);
```

Above query works with the regular table but throwing error using temporary tables. The alias for table `member_temp_2` i.e. t2 is getting this error "Can't reopen table: 't2'"

Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot reference a temporary table more than once in a statement. This is a limitation in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html Use CTE instead.

Comment: Thanks for figuring the issue. I have fixed the issue and my query is working now.